$\int \sin e^x dx$: Where did I go wrong?
So I created this integral for myself and the answer I got was completely different from the one others got. Here's how I did it (Please find my error) :
=$\int \sin e^x dx$
$u=e^x$
$du=e^xdx$
=$\int\sin(u)\frac1u\ du$
$\int uv\ dx=u\int v\ dx-\int(u'(\int v))\ dx$
=$u\int \sin u\ du-\int (u'(\int \sin u\ du))\ du$
=$u\!\cdot\!-\cos-\int(1\!\cdot\!-\cos u)\ du$
=$-u\cos u--\sin u$
=$\sin u-u\cos u$
=$\sin e^x-e^x\cos e^x + C $

What did others get?

Did you intend to reuse $u$ for substitution and intagration by parts?

It's bad t9 use $u$ in the $uv$ formula after already using the variable, I can tell what $u,v$ are substituted for.

@peterwhy they got the sine integral of e^x

After you obtained $$\int \sin e^x \, dx = \int \frac{1}{z} \sin z \, dz,$$ it is unclear how you applied integration by parts.  Presumably, you chose
$$u = \frac{1}{z}, \quad dv = \sin z \, dz.$$  This yields
$$du = -z^{-2} \, dz = -\frac{1}{z^2} \, dz, \quad v = \int \sin z \, dz = -\cos z.$$
Then the formula
$$\int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du$$
gives
$$\int \frac{1}{z} \sin z \, dz = -\frac{1}{z} \cos z - \int \frac{1}{z^2} \cos z \, dz.$$  The integrand
$$\frac{1}{z^2} \cos z$$
is no easier to integrate than $$\frac{1}{z} \sin z.$$  As such, I would consider your application of integration by parts to be incorrect--in particular, your calculation of the derivative of $1/z$ and the evaluation of the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z^2} \cos z$.
Alternatively, if you had chosen
$$u = \sin z, \quad dv = \frac{1}{z} \, dz,$$
this would give
$$du = \cos z \, dz, \quad v = \int \frac{1}{z} \, dz = \log z.$$
The lack of $\log z$ in your work is the reason why I did not think that you made this choice, and that you must have chosen the substitution I showed above.  Continuing, this would yield
$$\int \frac{1}{z} \sin z \, dz = \sin z \log z - \int \cos z \log z \, dz.$$  The latter integral of $\cos z \log z$ is, again, not expressible as an elementary closed form antiderivative.

Thanks for the help. I just realized I, for some unknown reason, used z instead of 1/z in the derivative part.
